# Windows Device Drivers with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, drivers

**Overview:**
I'm working on some windows service using Visual Basic 2010, which deployed on all enterprise PCs to collect all machines devices Ids, and monitors any hardware change then send these IDs and names back to a database to be as a reference for any unknown device in the future.

**My question**: I need to implement a new function in this service to collect machines device drivers, compress it and then send it back to the database as two parts First, the device description data. Second, the compress driver files to be used later. I search many times but I could not reach out any useful example for collecting these driver files. so how can I do that?.

Comment: Sorry John, I did not understand what you mean. I want some way to go through about writing this function.

Comment: Have you started to do this, or are you asking for us to do it for you?

Comment: I don't know from where should I start, This is my issue.

Comment: [so] isn't a good site for "where do I start" questions. Do search about "WMI", though.

Comment: I already used WMI to get devices IDs while I could not collect each device driver files and this is my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for reading devices inf files to get driver files bundle in this url: http://archive.devx.com/dotnet/discussions/040902/cominterop.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 For Each drive In Environment.GetLogicalDrives
            Dim Driver As DriveInfo = New DriveInfo(drive)

            If Driver.DriveType = DriveType.Removable Or Driver.DriveType = DriveType.Fixed Then

                ComboBox1.Items.Add(drive)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: It seems you did not get my point, I'm talking about Windows device drivers not drives